# Adjusting dimensions in one axis affects the size on other axes

Tags: scale, dimensions

I have a mesh and when I try to scale it by adjusting the dimensions (X dimension for example) in the N panel, the rest of the dimensions (Y,Z) decrease in size. How do I make this stop? I've already done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  and apply scale.

Answer (score 0):

Scale with <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd>  and only X axis will decrease in scale.